# why Hex data output differently?

Tags: c++, hex

I am writing a very simple code to test the Hex data on c++

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char bytestosend[4] = {0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x08};

    cout << &bytestosend << endl;
}
```

The data that comes on the terminal is : 0xbfa1ef58

how could this happen ? 
and when I remove the '&' it gives me strange symbols

Comment: Using the ampersand is giving you the memory location of your array, not the contents of it. If you remove the ampersand, you're printing a non-null-terminated string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `&` it is outputting the address of the array and when you don't it is printing it as ASCII data.

Comment: Doesn't it also need a null byte `0x0`?

Comment: Yes, it will most likely print a bunch of gibberish as it goes off the end of the array.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Only string literals initialized with `"..."` have a terminating null character put in for you.

Comment: @GuyGreer Yes I know but since he's using a char array and he isn't initializing it with a string literal, isn't he suppose to explicitly add the null byte?

Comment: @0x499602D2 If he wants to be able to use it as a string, yes.

Comment: @Volte what should I do to print the data inside ?

Comment: The easiest way is probably using `printf` in the `<cstdio>` header.

`printf("0x%02X 0x%02X 0x%02X 0x%02X", bytestosend[0], bytestosend[1], bytestosend[2], bytestosend[3]);`

Answer (score 1):

The '&' means 'address of' in this context. You are printing the location of `bytestosend` in memory rather than the contents of it.

Remove that '&' and you won't get what you want either. Now that stream insertion operator (`operator >>`) sees a `char` array, so it's going to try to print your array as if it was a string. Your array isn't null terminated, so that output might go on for a while.

If you want to print all four of the elements of `bytestosend` in hex use something like this:

```
std::cout.flags (std::ios::hex | std::ios::showbase);
std::cout << int(bytestosend[0]) << ", "
          << int(bytestosend[1]) << ", "
          << int(bytestosend[2]) << ", "
          << int(bytestosend[3]) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Oops. Code fixed. `std::ostream & operator<<(char)` interprets the input as a `char` rather than an integer. You need to cast to non-char integral type to have the input interpreted as a number rather than a character.

Comment: Zeyad Serag - You do not need those brackets around `int`. I rolled back your edit. I prefer not to use things like `(TypeName) x`. This is a C-style cast. I always compile with warnings on use of C-style casts. `TypeName(x)` is a functional style cast. This is illegal syntax in C, but keep in mind that C++ is not C.